# C++ How to populate a static array of strings with new strings in different locations?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strcpy

Say I got this

```
char* MapIds[5000] = { "Northeast Asia","Hanyang","Pusan","Pyongyang","Shanghai","Beijing","Hong Kong", /*...5000 values etc../* };
```

I tried

```
strcpy(MapIds[0], "gfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg");
```

But it crashes

How Do I keep changing them around without messing up the strings in other elements.

I dont want to use std::string or vector  those cause crazy slow compile times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you try to copy into a literal string (`"Northeast Asia"`).

In C++ a literal string is really a ***constant*** array of characters, any attempt to modify such an array will lead to *undefined behavior* (which can sometimes express themselves as crashes).

If you want to make `MapIds[0]` *point* to a new string, then you simply use assignment:

```
MapIds[0] = "gfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg";
```

---

Because literal strings are constant arrays of characters, C++ doesn't really allow you to have a `char*` to point to them, you must use `const char*`:

```
const char* MapIds[] = { ... };
```

However, a much better solution is to not use C-style strings and `char` pointers (`const` or not) at all, but only use `std::string`:

```
std::string MapIds[] = { ... };
```

Then you can modify the strings in the array itself, using plain assignment as shown above.

Comment: As a supplement, using `char*` to point to a string literal is wrong.

Comment: how do I get a `c_str()` into the array at some element?

Comment: without `char*` I get 
`Error C2078 too many initializers`
`Error E0146 too many initializer values`

Comment: `std::string` with 5000 strings takes like 40 seconds to compile though and the `char* MapIds[] = {}` only takes like 2-3 seconds. thats why I dont want to use `std::string`

Comment: @SSpoke it works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/8PqCA7 are you sure you have no more than 5000 strings in your initialiser? Adding an additional string to the linked code reproduces the `too many initializers` error

Comment: @SSpoke To be honest, if you have 5000 strings in the code itself, you're not doing it right (IMO). I would simply have the strings in a simple text-file, one string per line. Then use `while (std::getline(file, input))` and add each string to a `std::vector<std::string>`. Compile-time should be even faster than what you have now, and the extra run-time needed should be minimal even with a slow disk. Especially if you do it only once.

Comment: @SSpoke And depending on the problem and use-case, maybe you should even consider using a database? Especially if you want to make changes and have them be saved.